# Why does the delete button hovertext say it is a vote, while the button itself doesn't?

Tags: support, voting, deleted-questions

### Question

I asked a question on Physics Stack Exchange, and it was bad and I wanted to delete it, so I hovered the "delete" button, Which clearly **says**

> Vote to delete this post

The description of the button says Vote (to delete my own question)

I click it, expecting a vote. (Ideally I would want to delete it)

But I can't (which is expected) because a answer (I have also accepted it since it did clear my question up) is on it.

My question is why is it when hovered - "vote to ..." - while the button itself says "delete" not "vote to Delete"?

Note this is not specific to any site, this is for *all* the sites.

#### references

I do not see any question asked like this; on this site that is.

It also warns me  when clicked - on the deletion button

> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

I click yes; but still (not possible)

(Which again - is logical enough) but if I can't vote to delete it, it's a bit confusing.

and this is my **first question on meta** so please, if I can improve it - point it out!

Comment: @RobertLongson I am specifically asking about the function if it is a bug. I did get help, but if my question is being downvoted - obviously I feel the urge to do something about it to make something better of it  :) *even though I got help*.  I mean, that is what the down voting is for, to mark "this question is bad", so I would rather not want to just sit and relax and not try to make any attempt of making my question better (this is also for the future readers).

Comment: If it's downvoted edit it to improve it.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, of course - it's just if I have asked a question that is off topic (but I did try to make it on topic) and it is still being downvoted- it's dififcult :) but yes, I agree that's what I also do *in most cases* - thanks!

Comment: last comment: if I don't know how to improve a down-voted question there is indeed little for me to do.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't know it was a vote first, and if it was a vote, I was just unsure why I could vote to close it (that worked) but vote to delete(didn't) but yes; although it wouldn't take up an enormous amount but yes I agree

Comment: **note if this question is bad in itself; I would appreciate it if I got told why, so I can make it less bad**. :)

Comment: still trying to improve it. A bit troublesome.

Comment: oh and; if the downvotes(on this question) is because people think I do not think people put in effort in answers; **this is wrong**. I do. And the question is (hopefully **clearly** about the function itself, and not any user behavior/effort) (was also the reason I posted it here, and not in philosophy) :) I understand people do take time(I myself included) writing questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I asked a moderator, and this is what he said:

> As users have invested time into writing answers, it would be unfair
> to them to delete it.

This should answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

When you reach 10,000 reputation you get the ability to vote to delete closed questions. If you reach 20,000 reputation you can vote to delete answers too.

In these cases it's definitely a vote to delete because you'll need to find at least two other people with a similarly high reputation to agree with you and cast delete votes too.

So the hover text reflects reality, you actually are voting to delete. It's just as the post author, if you can vote, your vote is binding. The hover text simply doesn't customise to each individual situation.

The [help privilege for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) explains why you can't delete your question.

> We don't like to lose great answers!